# iOS equivolent of Android toast

Tags: c#, ios, api, webview, toast

I have an App that has native top navigation bar and drop down burger menu. The rest of the App is a web view from a C# API.

The webview has purchasing and the top navigation bar shows a balance (currency amount).

In Android I'm using JavaScript toast to update purchases from the webview, to the balance on the native top navigation bar.

My question is how ca I do this for iOS. It's something I'm struggling with and cannot find a solution.

Can anyone help or has anyone solved this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no default equivalent for toast in iOS. There are plenty of libs that mimic the same behaviour.

Comment: You'll need to use an open-source solution.  This one is popular on github:  https://github.com/devxoul/Toaster